# awk splitting problem with space

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-formatting

I failed to split after the first space with awk.

```
$ grep ">" Supplemental_dataset_07_NbE_CDS.fasta | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t" } {print $1}' | head
>NbD053290.1 Partial, glutelin type-B 2-like  (XP_016462855.1)
>NbD053289.2 GDSL esterase/lipase At2g38180-like  (XP_016505556.1)
>NbD053288.1 SUMO-conjugating enzyme SCE1  (XP_019223445.1)
>NbD053287.1 bifunctional epoxide hydrolase 2-like  (XP_016470817.1)
>NbD053286.1 uncharacterized protein LOC109221334 isoform X1  (XP_019241352.1)
>NbD053285.2 uncharacterized protein LOC107817905  (XP_016499316.1)
>NbD053284.3 cell division cycle protein 123 homolog  (XP_019248046.1)
>NbD053283.1 Partial, probable rhamnogalacturonate lyase B  (XP_009789094.1)
>NbD053282.1 aluminum-activated malate transporter 2-like  (XP_009760052.1)
>NbD053281.1 Partial, uncharacterized protein LOC107803999  (XP_016483291.1)
```

Unfortunately, the below command removed part of the description:

```
grep ">" Supplemental_dataset_07_NbE_CDS.fasta | awk 'BEGIN { FS = " " } {print $1","$2}' | head

>NbD053290.1,Partial,
>NbD053289.1,GDSL
>NbD053288.1,SUMO-conjugating
>NbD053287.1,bifunctional
>NbD053286.1,uncharacterized
>NbD053285.1,uncharacterized
>NbD053284.1,cell
>NbD053283.1,Partial,
>NbD053282.1,aluminum-activated
>NbD053281.1,Partial,
```

How would it be possible to modify the above command to create this output:

```
>NbD053290.1,Partial, glutelin type-B 2-like  (XP_016462855.1)
>NbD053289.2,GDSL esterase/lipase At2g38180-like  (XP_016505556.1)
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Edit your question and provide the contents of the file without the commands.

Comment: Is the call to `head` actually a requirement of your use case, or did you only include it to create a short excerpt of the data as an example of how the input looks like?

Answer (score 2):

This will replace your whole `grep | awk | head` pipeline:

```
awk '/>/{sub(/ /,","); print; if (++c == 10) exit}' Supplemental_dataset_07_NbE_CDS.fasta
```

Comment: @AdminBee Right, code-only answers often end up in the "**possibly** low quality post" review queue and it's then up to people familiar with the domain to decide if it is low quality or not. Yes, the OP might be using `head` for that purpose but idk so I just gave the OP what they asked for and `modify the above command` - hopefully it's easy to see what part of my code is implementing `head` and modify it if not required.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F" " '{ sub(" ",","); print; }' input
>NbD053290.1,Partial, glutelin type-B 2-like  (XP_016462855.1)
>NbD053289.2,GDSL esterase/lipase At2g38180-like  (XP_016505556.1)
>NbD053288.1,SUMO-conjugating enzyme SCE1  (XP_019223445.1)
>NbD053287.1,bifunctional epoxide hydrolase 2-like  (XP_016470817.1)
>NbD053286.1,uncharacterized protein LOC109221334 isoform X1  (XP_019241352.1)
>NbD053285.2,uncharacterized protein LOC107817905  (XP_016499316.1)
>NbD053284.3,cell division cycle protein 123 homolog  (XP_019248046.1)
>NbD053283.1,Partial, probable rhamnogalacturonate lyase B  (XP_009789094.1)
>NbD053282.1,aluminum-activated malate transporter 2-like  (XP_009760052.1)
>NbD053281.1,Partial, uncharacterized protein LOC107803999  (XP_016483291.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
$ raku -pe 's/\s/,/;'
>NbD053290.1,Partial, glutelin type-B 2-like  (XP_016462855.1)
>NbD053289.2,GDSL esterase/lipase At2g38180-like  (XP_016505556.1)
```

OR

```
$ raku -pe 's:5th/<.ws>/,/;' glutelin.txt
>NbD053290.1,Partial, glutelin type-B 2-like  (XP_016462855.1)
>NbD053289.2,GDSL esterase/lipase At2g38180-like  (XP_016505556.1)
```

https://raku.org/